# Repeat alarm for 5 minutes

Tags: android

I have an alarm application that will ring continuously until I stop but now I want the alarm to ring for a period of time. Help me to do it:

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm On");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Alarm_activity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alarm_activity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        int repeatSeconds = 5;
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                repeatSeconds * 1000, pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        setAlarmText("");
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
    }
}
```

This is the alarm start function.

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573341/scheduling-alarm-every-2-minutes-android

Comment: not this...i want to ring for period of time...if i give 5 minutes then alarm must ring for 5 minutes

Comment: not possible, If you find some way than notify me

Comment: its posible. I use sharedpreference and Countdown timer..it works cool